# Evaluatiing a limit as x -> 0

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Can't get rid of the uncertainty

$\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{2+Sin(3x)-2Cos(2x)}{2+Sin(3x)-2Cos(3x)}\right)^\frac{3}{x}$

```
Limit[((2 + Sin[3 x] - 2 Cos[2 x])/(2 + Sin[3 x] - 2 Cos[3 x]))^(3/x), x -> 0]
```

Comment: You really should show the Mathematica code you used so that others do not have to type things from an image. But It works for me. `ClearAll[x];
expr = (2 + Sin[3 x] - 2 Cos[2 x])/(2 + Sin[3 x] - 2 Cos[3 x]);
Limit[expr^(3/x), x -> 0]` and it gives `1/Exp[5]` That is why showing the code used is important. You could have made an error somewhere.

Comment: @Nasser, how did you get 1/Exp[5], can you show ?

Comment: Please see screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/g00wh.png)

Comment: This is an (easy) math-question, so remember logarithms would help

Comment: @mgamer,can you show the exact solution if possible step-by- step ,please

Comment: Do a series expansion about `x == 0`. The constant term is the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Mathematica there is no step-by-step. One simply evaluates

```
Limit[((2 + Sin[3 x] - 2 Cos[2 x])/(2 + Sin[3 x] - 2 Cos[3 x]))^(3/x), x -> 0]
```

and gets

> `1/E^5`

#### Visual confirmation

```
Plot[
  {((2 + Sin[3 x] - 2 Cos[2 x])/(2 + Sin[3 x] - 2 Cos[3 x]))^(3/x),
   1/E^5}, {x, -.5, 1},
  PlotLabels -> Automatic,
  PlotRange -> {0, Automatic},
  PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, {.02, Automatic}},
  ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: plot]